# Increasing the tolerance of Droppable in jQueryUi

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Is there any method by which we can increase the tolerance value of Droppable?

Currently it accepts 4 values: fit, intersect, pointer and touch.

But I want a specific case whenever my draggable element comes in the vicinity of the droppable element, it should accept it.

A valid option can be specifying a grid say [3,3] which accepts any draggable in or around this grid.